# How to check from inside a container if another container is running on port

Tags: bash, docker-compose, port, docker-container

I am running 2 containers at the same time (connected via docker-compose on setting    links && depends_on).
The depends on is not enough, so I want the script that run on entryphone of one of the container to check if the other container is running already on some port.

I tried:

```
#!bin/bash
until nc -z w10 <container_name> 3306
do
echo waiting for db to be ready...
sleep 2
done
echo code is ready
```

But this is not working..

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `depends_on` approach. However, you can use some of the advanced setting of this command. Please, read the documentation of [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

You can use the [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script to exactly achieve what you need. Extracted from the documentation:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `docker-compose` to orchestrate your services a better way would be to use [`condition: service_healthy` of the `depends_on` long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on). So instead of manually waiting in one container for the *other* to become available `docker-compose` will start the former only after the latter became `healthy`, i.e. available.

If the depended-on container does not have a specified [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) in its image already you can manually define it in the `docker-compose.yml` with the [`healthcheck` attribute](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck).

Example with a `mariadb` database using the included [`healthcheck.sh` script](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/bf522faed0b15da89dc40dbcd2390d423ab2adb7/10.7/healthcheck.sh):

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: myapp/image
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    healthcheck:
      test: "healthcheck.sh --connect"
```

With this `docker-compose up` will first start the `db` service and wait until the `db` service becomes `healthy`, i.e. is ready to accept connections, and only then will start the `app` service which can immediately connect to the `db`.